# Installing Meteor packages globally

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

Is there a way to install meteor packages globally?

So, having the once globally installed packages installable without internet connection for projects created later, avoid repetitive downloading, and other benefits one may imagine.

Like in Node.js, using npm command (of Node Package Manager) with `-g` flag, `npm install -g`, doing so npm installs node packages into a global directory and when wanted to be loaded from javascript programs, loading from there if available, as well as looking in and loading packages from project's node modules folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meteor already downloads packages into a global repository that all your local apps benefit off of.

So if you `meteor add iron:router@1.0.7` it is downloaded and added to your project. Next time another project requires the same version, it is used off that same spot.

Also, there is a `PACKAGES_DIR` environment variable, when set, allows you to keep your own local packages centrally, so that you can share them among projects. In fact, you can keep that on a network drive (NFS) which your whole team can mount and consume centrally.

Yet, there is an inherent problem. Meteor's version resolver looks up for updates **unless you pin down your package dependency versions** so that is exactly why meteor seems to be so desperate to be connected.

Even if *you* pin your dependencies, the packages you depend on may not have (which apparently is the case for most packages) so Meteor keeps looking for updates to the whole package tree and downloads those that it deems satisfying the version constraint resolver.

The good news is, they are constantly improving their tooling, requiring lower number of lookups, faster builds, better search etc.

All in all, in essence, there is not much you can do unless Meteor provides some way of hosting an entire mirror of its package repository for you to consume offline. And I guess it is very unlikely to happen.

Meteor is a tool for the connected world and it does assume your connectivity. Heck, the whole journey begins with a `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`

And yes, it would be great if we could hack away on a remote beach, or the 12 hour flight to that beach.

Until then, happy coding online ;)

Comment: Thanks. what I meant was not ability to use offline the entire meteor package repository which is already the most unusual for the most package managers as normal, like npm, or even os package managers like freebsd pkg.
From your explanation, do you mean the installed meteor packages by `meteor add` is added to a central global directory, and the project in which I have issued meteor add just copies this package dir in its dir. If so, next meteor add issued for the same package in another project would be normally supposed to just copy package dir to this project dir, which I mean by offline..

Comment: I think this is the way Meteor do, and you have meant by "..same spot.". But one must give the same exact version number to have it installed from the existing copy in the central global dir in the local machine.

Comment: It does not copy packages to your project's package directory. It just copies them to your build at build time which gets into the .meteor/local/build directory (which is just a tmp place to serve your app during development) of your project root. Regarding version numbers, you don't need to request an exact version for that kind of match. Meteor's version constraints resolver works separately for each of your local apps, and when two of your apps happen to require the same version, it only gets downloaded once into your global package repository and from there into your local build.